# Area 51 and Careers favicons are loaded with an absolute scheme

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, ssl

The Area 51 favicon is loaded with an absolute (http) scheme, which makes my pretty green lock go away when I open the site switcher:

[image: Area 51 favicon loaded with absolute scheme]

All of the links to notifications et al also use the http scheme, though I suppose that's expected until SSL support is fully implemented. In the case of the favicon though, Area 51 is the odd one out, which makes this feel like a bug.

The Careers favicon exhibits the same problem, with the additional downside of seemingly being loaded without me even having to click on the site switcher button and thus breaking the secure connection right away.

Comment: Free hand red X. Nice!

Comment: A free hand red circle somewhere would really improve this question :-D

Comment: @Laf: You're not [thinking far enough](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a6MAY.png).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Woah, we definitely need this in more screenshots posted on MSO ;)